# Move a Range of cells based on Cell Content

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I am trying to use openpyxl to clean up some data ripped from a series of PDFs. The data is coming from a pandas dataframe, so the first cell on each row is the index, and based on that I want to move the range of data in a specific manner. The basic idea is to take data looking like this:

```
1 abc def ghi
2 jkl mno pqr
1 stu vwx yza
2 bcd efg hij
...
```

to look like this:

```
1 abc def ghi jkl mno pqr
2 null null null null
1 stu vwx yza bcd efg hij
2 null null null null
...
```

The code I'm currently running isn't throwing any errors, but it's also just not doing anything to the sheet. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
excel_file = load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Jake\\Documents\\Shared-VB\\upload 2.5.23\\Excel Result.xlsx")
sh = excel_file.active

for i in range(1, sh.max_row + 1):
    if sh.cell(row=i, column=1).value == "2":
        sh.move_range("B{i}:D{i}", rows=-1, cols=3)

excel_file.save("C:\\Users\\Jake\\Documents\\Shared-VB\\upload 2.5.23\\Final Result.xlsx")
```

**UPDATE:**

It looks like comparing the value as a string was "the" issue.

I changed it to:

```
for i in range(1, sh.max_row + 1):
    if sh.cell(row=i, column=1).value == 4:
        sh.move_range("B{i}:D{i}", rows=-1, cols=3)
```

which gave me the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Work Projects\Python\Contract Extraction\contract_extraction_xlm_1.py", line 23, in <module>
    sh.move_range("B{i}:D{i}", rows=-1, cols=3)
  File "C:\Users\Jake\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 772, in move_range
    cell_range = CellRange(cell_range)
  File "C:\Users\Jake\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\cell_range.py", line 53, in __init__
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(range_string)
  File "openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 135, in openpyxl.utils.cell.range_boundaries
ValueError: B{i}:D{i} is not a valid coordinate or range
[Finished in 923ms]
```

**So now the issue is that I am not sure how to make the coordinates context-sensitive based on the row that was checked in the for loop.**

Comment: I dont see how your input data corresponds with your code. The code sample loops through column A (index column) from row 1 to max rows looking for a cell with value '4'. Is each index number is in a separate cell A1, A2, A3 etc then A,B,C cells B1 - D1. How would any column A value equal 4 and why 4. How is the output formatted? A1 - F2?

Comment: Why are you comparing with a string? The code, as written, will probably have side effects with you moving cells whilst looping over them.

Comment: @moken - I understand your confusion and I apologize for the lack of clarity. I've edited the post to make the data and the code a little clearer. All the indices will be in column A, and the data I want to move will be in columns B, C, D. The index will determine how the data needs to be shifted. So, data in index '1' will not be moved, data in index '2' will be moved up one row and right three columns. There will be many different subsets concatenated into this data set that I'm working with, which is why I need to loop over them rather than just hardcoding the coordinates of each one.

Comment: @Charlie Clark - Good catch on comparing with a string, that seems to be an issue here. Once I changed it to compare an integer, it gave me: "ValueError: B{i}:D{i} is not a valid coordinate or range". So I guess I'm not sure how to phrase the coordinates in sh.move_range() it so that it will grab the necessary cells based on the row that was checked in the loop.

Comment: `ws.move_range()` takes either a range string or a `CellRange()` object, which is easier to parametrise. Your issue is the range string. This should either be an f-string use the `.format()` method. All this is easier if you stick with the API.

Answer (score 0):

Per Charlie Clark: ws.move_range() takes either a range string or a CellRange() object, which is easier to parametrise. Your issue is the range string. This should either be an f-string use the .format() method. All this is easier if you stick with the API.